# Fix external event item start/end time with background per rooms

Tags: fullcalendar

i'm using fullcalendar version 3 with external event. and my problem was that wanted to fix dropped point when drag/drop left side item to calendar.

for example, if external "My event 1" drag to "test1 room" (has start:13:00:00/end:17:00:00 time attribute) calendar. 
"My event 1" will be on 13:00:00 start and 17:00:00 end time **ONLY**. never change to another time on "test1 room" row.

```
$(function() { // document ready


    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });


    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        now: '2016-01-07',
        editable: true, // enable draggable events
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
                type: 'timeline',
                duration: { days: 3 }
            }
        },
        resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
        resources: [
            { id: 'a', title: 'test1 room', start:"2016-01-07T13:00:00",end: '2016-01-07T17:00:00' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'test2 room', eventColor: 'green' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'test3 room', eventColor: 'orange' },

        ],
        events: [
            { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2016-01-07T02:00:00', end: '2016-01-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1' }

        ],
        drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
            console.log('drop', date.format(), resourceId);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
            console.log('eventReceive', event);
        },
        eventDrop: function(event) { // called when an event (already on the calendar) is moved
            console.log('eventDrop', event);
        }
    });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To stop events being dragged around after they're placed on the calendar, you can simply set the editable option:

```
editable: false
```

This stops internal dragging/dropping, but doesn't affect external dropping (which is controlled by the "droppable" option).

If you only want this rule to apply to specific events, you can set `editable: true` in general, but then set `editable: false` as a property of individual events - this will override the global setting. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ for details of which  settings can be over-ridden at the event level.

Comment: editable also helpful for me. thank you. and  my main problem was force set start/end time when drag/drop external item to calendar per rooms which has different start/end time like start:"2017-12-01T13:00", end:"2017-12-01T15:00". could you let me know how to do this?

Comment: Ok. I think I misunderstood the question a bit. Are you saying the rooms have certain fixed time constraints onto which an event must be dropped? e.g. there might only be one or two possible times available for any given room on each day? Or literally the only available slot is the one defined as custom start/end properties of the room (in the resources settings)?

Comment: e.g. for "test 1 rooM" can an event literally be only inserted onto that one day (e.g. 7th Jan 2016 between 1pm and 5pm), or do you really mean the same time period every day? Must the event last exactly 4hrs or can it be shorter? I am just thinking there may, or may not, be a better way of doing what you want using fullCalendar's API.

Comment: yes you're right. i am thinking about that for a month. please let me know. thank you so much ADyson.

Comment: In my comments I asked several questions, some of which don't allow for a "yes" answer. If you'd like me to try and help again, please answer them.

Comment: maximum event time could be 24hrs. i'm really mean the same time period every day per room.

Comment: Those two things seem to be contradict each other? The event can be up to 24hrs, but also it can only be a set time period in each day (e.g. between 1pm and 5pm)? I don't understand.

Comment: i mean e.g. the 24hrs is "start_time":"2017-12-07T00:00","end_time":"2017-12-07T23:59".  all events of in room  has start_time / end_time (e.g. as you, between 1pm and 5pm).

Comment: I know what 24hrs means...but the requirement is still not clear at all. You can't say the event can be up to 24hrs long **and** say it must be within 1pm and 5pm. It doesn't make any sense. Consider editing the question, or asking a new one with clearer requirements and examples. I cannot help you based on this info.